# Chrome in "full screen" mode (no title bar/toolbar) without actually being full screen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a large monitor that I divide up into regions with DisplayFusion.  If I want to watch web-based video, such as Netflix, it would be nice to be able to have Chrome run in full screen mode, but without actually taking up my entire monitor.

That is, I want just the web view of Chrome (no title bar, no address bar, no toolbar) to run at certain coordinates on the screen, and at a certain width and height.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 10?

You can try to split your screen for multitasking. The easiest way is to drag your Chrome window of video to one corner of the screen (left/right/top/bottom, whatever you want). Detailed instructions are [here](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-split-screen-on-windows?IR=T). Then you can make it full screen in that corner. The remaining area of the monitor you can use for other tasks.

For example this is what I do on my monitor (on MacOSX but I used to use Windows and it works quite the same). The youtube is playing fullscreen on the right and I am answering you on the left. With Windows, you can split your monitor more flexibly with the instruction link I shared above.

[image: my screen]

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm using Windows 10.  I have no problems setting up the split screen, but Chrome will show its title bar and address bar.  That's what I need to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Vivaldi browser can do that: https://vivaldi.com/
See the "Tab stacking, tab tiling and vertical tabs" section

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem.  My screen is already divided up, and I want to place totally chrome-less browser windows alongside other applications.  However!... out of curiosity, I downloaded Vivaldi and totally love it because they fixed the one thing the Chrome team took away some years ago... the backspace key!!  Finally, I can go back by pressing backspace.  For *years*, I've been hitting backspace with nothing happening, and now I can fix it.  So, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for this behaviour, a recent addition to the PowerToys collection called [Crop & Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/powertoys/crop-and-lock) allows this to be done.

It is not as convenient as a browser directly turning off its chrome for the current window on-demand as you can't resize the resulting window (you have to turn the feature off, resize the source, and turn it back on), and if used in conjunction with Always On Top you need to re-toggle this before & after, but it does the basic trick and has the advantage of working with any browser and many other apps.